# (572.15 - 595.00),(3,692.05 - 3,757.00) If I want to convert from string to float, why would that happen?

Tags: python

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sys = ['DRREDDY','SUNPHARMA','DIVISLAB','CIPLA','AUROPHARMA','LUPIN','BIOCON','TORNTPHARM','RELIANCE','CADILAHC']
for n in sys:
    url = f"https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{n}.NS?p={n}.NS&.tsrc=fin-srch"
    headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'}
    r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    # praise = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
    # pr = soup.find_all('td',{'class':"Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"})[0].text
    pr1 = soup.find_all('td',{'class':"Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"})[4].text
    # op=  soup.find_all('td',{'class':"Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"})[1].find('span').text
   
    print( pr1)
```

Comment: can you briefly explain what happens, and how data looked before and after conversion

Comment: And also what you want to achieve.

And mostly: do not post screenshots of code: please copy and paste the code in the post

Comment: I get data 214.30 - 245.30 like this, I have to separate these two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
floats = list(map(lambda x: float(x.replace(",", "").strip()), pr1.split("-")))   
for your_float in floats:
    print(your_float, )
```

Comment: @KingDevil Did you try this code?